# ASP.NET MVC: How to implement a wild card SSL for more than one static domain on a single IP?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ssl, wildcard-subdomain

A wild card SSL allows any domain prefix:

```
*.mydomain.com accepts
ssl.mydomain.com
secure.mydomain.com
anything.mydomain.com
```

Given that MVC can route the request to the correct view based on the URL, is it as simple as loading the wildcard SSL cert on an IP, then use DNS to map the various names to the IP?

Answer (score 1):

Presuming you have each of the above setup as a separate site in IIS, you simply need to apply the certificate to each site through the IIS6 wizard or the IIS7 Bindings Menu.

In terms of SSL, the IP address does not matter, because the SSL Certificate is based on a DNS name, not an IP.

Comment: The question is whether you can have
https:// ssl.mydomain.com and 
https:// secure.mydomain.com
happen on the same IP under the same 443 SSL port?

Comment: I believe that is possible, you just have to add an additional binding.

Comment: How can they both be bound to the same socket endpoint? Which instance answers the knock?

Comment: All the domain names pointing to the single ip and ssl port would be answered by a single MVC instance, then route to the corresponding control method and view (or a single control method that would call the appropriate method.)